# How to make sikuli focus on Desktop screen

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

I am using VS CODE to develope a Robot with Robot Framework and Sikuli. When I run my script I get an error

> "could not find P(sage.png)"

This happen because the current screen is the VS CODE's screen and not the desktop  where the "sage.png" is.

What I can use in my script in order to focus on desktop screen first of all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked at the documentation of [sikuli](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appclass.html).
You can make use of the below method, where they have specifically talked about your issue.

```
classmethod focusedWindow()
```

> On Windows, this method always returns a region. When there is no
>   window opened on the desktop, the region may refer to a special window
>   such as the task bar or an icon in the system tray.

```
# highlight the currently fontmost window for 2 seconds
App.focusedWindow().highlight(2)

# save the windows region before
firstWindow = App.focusedWindow()
firstWindow.highlight(2)
```